# How to Make the Checkout Billing fields read only in Woo Commerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, billing

We have a website for orders that are then delivered. Now the thing is we want to utilize the details from the My Account Address Billing as the address to ship to, on checkout we want this populated from what's there but not allow the user to make any changes on that check out page Billing form.

This code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_fields','customization_readonly_billing_fields',10,1);
function customization_readonly_billing_fields($checkout_fields){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();;
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;
    foreach ( $checkout_fields['billing'] as $key => $field ){
        if($key == 'billing_address_1' || $key == 'billing_address_2'){
            $key_value = get_user_meta($user_id, $key, true);
            if( strlen($key_value)>0){
                $checkout_fields['billing'][$key]['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');
            }
        }
    }
    return $checkout_fields;
}
```

Only makes the Address part not be changed however everything else from first name, last name, cellphone, etc is able to be modified.

We need all those fields to be locked just as that code as locked the Address field to read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `if($key == 'billing_address_1' || $key == 'billing_address_2'){` this line all fields. check beloe code.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_fields','customization_readonly_billing_fields',10,1);
function customization_readonly_billing_fields($checkout_fields){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;
    foreach ( $checkout_fields['billing'] as $key => $field ){
        $key_value = get_user_meta($user_id, $key, true);
        if( $key_value != '' ){
            if( $key == 'billing_country' || $key == 'billing_state' || $key == 'billing_suburb' ){
                $checkout_fields['billing'][$key]['custom_attributes'] = array('disabled'=>'disabled');
            }else{
                $checkout_fields['billing'][$key]['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');
            }
        }
    }
    return $checkout_fields;
}
```

For `billing_country`, `billing_state` and `billing_suburb`, you have to pass value in hidden because the select dropdown disabled the option value is not passed when you click place order and in order to solve this issue we can add hidden fields with our value.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'billing_countryand_state_hidden_field');
function billing_countryand_state_hidden_field($checkout){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;
    echo '<input type="hidden" class="input-hidden" name="billing_country"  value="'.get_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_country', true).'">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" class="input-hidden" name="billing_state"  value="'.get_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_state', true).'">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" class="input-hidden" name="billing_suburb"  value="'.get_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_suburb', true).'">';

}
```

**Tested and works**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is almost perfect, the only thing it isn't locking is the select list drop down, possible to lock that ?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Still drop down presents itself, using state and a custom one called suburb.

Comment: can you share your site link?

Comment: Sure thing, https://foodline.co.za/

Comment: Did you add the code?

Comment: Thanks alot Bhautik, but now the thing is my drop downs are locked as wanted but everything else is editable

Comment: I  have updated my answer

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Works like a dream, can not thank you enough for assisting through the trial and error phase

Comment: Hey there, so finally doing a test run but get this error:  Please enter an address to continue. Even though the fields are populated from the My Account page

Comment: Okay so I solved that part (Country had to be included) however when I display my contents on the admin area the Drop down field of suburb is empty , everything else I can display, using basic echo and p tags. Just Suburb is empty for some reason not capturing from the locked option field

Comment: what is your suburb field name?

Comment: billing_suburb is the field name

Comment: Still cant figure out how to get the drop down selection to show its data on the admin screen